# Ruby: Wrong number of Arguments for a subclass changes number of arguments

Tags: ruby, super

I am very new to Ruby and I have been looking for an answer to my question, but haven't found an answer yet.
This is my code:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(aName, anAge)
    @name = aName
    @age = anAge
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  def initialize(aName, anAge, aBreed)
    @breed = aBreed
    super(aName, anAge, aBreed)
  end
end
```

When I try to create a new cat object with defining three parameters, it says: ArgumentError: Wrong number of Arguments (3 for 2).
But when I do the same thing with two parameters I get (2 for 3).

I can't seem to figure it out...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your super class `Animal` constructor takes only two parameters `aName` and `anAge`. so you should only pass first two arguments of `Cat` to `Animal`.

```
class Cat < Animal
  def initialize(aName, anAge, aBreed)
    @breed = aBreed
    super(aName, anAge)
  end
end
```

Comment: Wooo! Thank you! That was burning a hole in my head, but now super makes more sense, thanks again!